# Writing Test class for Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I am having problem when i am trying to write Test Class for Wrapper Class.

**Apex class**

```
public with sharing class InlineCtrl {

    public List<Opportunity> oplist {get;set;}
    public List<WrapperMethod> wrap{get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> savelist{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public String opget{get;set;}
  //  public boolean show{get;set;}
    public boolean edit{get;set;}


    integer i=0;
    public InlineCtrl()
    {
        oplist=new List<Opportunity>();
        wrap=new List<WrapperMethod>();

        for(Opportunity o:[Select id,Name,StageName,AccountID from Opportunity])
        {
            WrapperMethod w=new WrapperMethod(o,false,i,false);
            wrap.add(w);
            i++;
        }
        system.debug('--Wrap Size--'+wrap.size());
        System.debug('--In Constructor--');

    }



    public void editview()
    {
      Integer q=Integer.valueof(opget);
       wrap.get(q).selected=true;
       wrap.get(q).editble=true;



    }

    public void saveview()
    {

      Integer q=Integer.valueof(opget);
      update wrap.get(q).opp;
      wrap.get(q).selected=false;
      wrap.get(q).editble=false;
   }

    public void deleteview()
    {

       Integer q=Integer.valueof(opget);
       delete wrap.get(q).opp;
       wrap.remove(q);


    }

    public void cancelview()
    {
       Integer q=Integer.valueof(opget);
       wrap.get(q).selected=false;
       wrap.get(q).editble=false;

    }

    public class WrapperMethod
    {
        public opportunity opp{get;set;}
        Public boolean selected{get;set;}
        public integer index{get;set;}
        public boolean editble{get;set;}

        public WrapperMethod(opportunity o,Boolean s,Integer i,Boolean q)
        {
            opp=o;
            selected=s;
            index=i;
            editble=q;
        }

    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class InlineCtrlTest
{



    static testMethod void InlineTest()
    {

        opportunity o=new opportunity(Name='Test');
       Boolean selected;
       Integer index;
       Boolean editble;
       String opget='0';
       List<InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod> w;

       InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod testWrap=new InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod(o,selected=false,index=1,editble=false); 

        InlineCtrl inline=new InlineCtrl();
        inline.editview();

        inline.saveview();
        inline.deleteview();
        inline.cancelview();




    }
}
```

Comment: wats the problem ? r u getting any error ? can u post the error and possibly any debug logs

Comment: There is no error but my problem is how can i access my Methods in testclass

Comment: I am getting this error Class.InlineCtrlTest.InlineTest: line 20, column 1

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan - when you say "this error" my crystal ball does not understand.....luckily the issue was very obvious..

Comment: @Eric how can i access method

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan - Look down. Answer is below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling it wrong:

Change

```
InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod testWrap=new InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod(o,selected=false,index=1,editble=false);
```

to

```
InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod testWrap=new InlineCtrl.WrapperMethod(o,false,1,false);
```

You have other issue with your test class though. It really does absolutely nothing but cover lines...... You really should be testing business processes and asserting that the results are acceptable using asserts