# Apex test method for wrapper classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I looked at these existing questions but they didn't answer my specific case:

- [Writing test code for wrapper class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21735/writing-test-code-for-wrapper-class)
- [Writing Test class for Wrapper Class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87533/writing-test-class-for-wrapper-class)

in my controller I have the below code which stores all the Notes and Attachments on my requests object:

```
@TestVisible public List<wNA> rowList {get; set;}  

@TestVisible public class wNA implements Comparable {
    // see 
    //      https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/how-to-sort-a-custom-list-of-notes-and-attachments-by-lastmodifieddate
    // and
    //      https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106385/notes-attachments-wrapper-class-not-sorting-by-lastmodifieddate-correctly?noredirect=1#comment145451_106385

    // calling the Sort method on a List type derived from this class calls the below comparison for each member of the list
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {            
        system.debug('Sorting difference: ' + (LastModifiedDate.getTime()-((wNA)o).LastModifiedDate.getTime()).intValue());
        return -(LastModifiedDate.getTime()-((wNA)o).LastModifiedDate.getTime()).intValue();            
    }

    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string fileName {get; set;}
    public string createdBy {get; set;}
    public datetime LastModifiedDate {get; set;}
    public string contentType {get; set;}
    public string LastModifiedDtStr {get; set;}
}
```

In the constructor I call the below function to retrieve all Notes and attachments and sort them like this:

```
public void getNotes_and_Attachments(){
    system.debug('RFSCController Constructor GET ATTACHMENTS');
    rowList = new List <wNA>();

    List<Attachment> lstAttachments= [SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate, contentType, OwnerId from Attachment where ParentId =:recordid];                                

        for (Integer iDx=0; iDx<lstAttachments.size(); iDx++){
            wNA tr = new wNA();

            String strLastModified = lstAttachments[iDx].LastModifiedDate.format('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm');
            System.debug('  @@@@  Attachments strLastModified: '+strLastModified);

            tr.Type = 'Attachment';
            tr.Id = lstAttachments[iDx].Id;
            tr.fileName = lstAttachments[iDx].Name;
            tr.createdBy =  [SELECT Id, Name from User where Id =:lstAttachments[iDx].OwnerId].Name; 
            tr.contentType = lstAttachments[iDx].contentType;
            tr.LastModifiedDate = lstAttachments[iDx].LastModifiedDate; 
            tr.LastModifiedDtStr = strLastModified;
            rowList.add(tr);
        }

    system.debug('RFSCController Constructor GET NOTES');
    List<Note> lstNotes= [SELECT Id, Title, ParentId, LastModifiedDate, createdbyid, body FROM Note where ParentId =:recordid];

        for (Integer iDx=0; idx<lstNotes.size(); idx++){
            wNA tr = new wNA();

            String strLastModified = lstNotes[iDx].LastModifiedDate.format('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm');
            System.debug('  @@@@  strLastModified: '+strLastModified);
            // MAILSHOT New, Save, Edit, Save, Submit, Approve Test 
            tr.Type = 'Note';
            tr.Id = lstNotes[iDx].Id;
            tr.fileName = lstNotes[iDx].Title;
            tr.createdBy = [SELECT Id, Name from User where Id =:lstNotes[iDx].createdbyid].Name; 
            tr.LastModifiedDate = lstNotes[iDx].LastModifiedDate;           
            tr.LastModifiedDtStr = strLastModified;
            rowList.add(tr);
        }           

    rowList.sort(); 
}
```

Now in my test class I want to test that wrapper calss code.

I tried this but I cannot get it to compile:

```
controller.wNA wNA = new controller.wNA();
```

and I also tried: `//rowList=controller.getNotes_and_Attachments();`

the compile error I am getting is:

> Invalid type: controller.wNA

Comment: See my answer below, but as a suggestion, instead of `for (Integer iDx=0; iDx<lstAttachments.size(); iDx++)`, have you tried `for (Attachment att : lstAttachments)`? It's an easier-to-read syntax

Comment: As an aside I don't think @testVisible does much. Your class is already public.

Comment: you have soql inside of for loops -- if your parent object has many notes and attachments, this will blow up on governor limits - better to query for users once and save result in a map

Comment: @crop1645: But what if different attachments and notes are added by different users? How would I handle that, as we need to show for each note/attachment the creator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the class name, not the instance name. You haven't posted your class name, so I assume it's `RFSCController` from the comments you've written in your code.

In that case, you initialise your variable by doing:

```
RFSCController.wNA wNA = new RFSCController.wNA();
```

Comment: my object is called `Request_For_System_Change__c` and my controller class is called `RequestForSystemChangeController` so I will try *RequestForSystemChangeController.wNA wNA = new RequestForSystemChangeController.wNA();*